# Reverse number (Python)

Tags: python, int, reverse

Обьясните код пожалуйста, нашел в таком месте где нет детального обьяснение.
Код переворачивает число.

```
oNumber = 125
revNum = 0

while(oNumber > 0):
    remainder = oNumber % 10
    revNum = (revNum * 10) + remainder
    oNumber = oNumber // 10

print("Reversed number is: {}".format(revNum))
```

Comment: Добавьте в теле цикла вывод на печать всех переменных. После этого станет понятно что делает код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
revNum = 0

while oNumber > 0:
    remainder = oNumber % 10  # Получение последнего числа (остаток от деления на 10)
    revNum = (revNum * 10) + remainder  # Сдвигает предыдущее число (умножение на 10) и прибавляет последнее число
    oNumber = oNumber // 10  # Убирает последнее число (целая часть от деления на 10)

print("Reversed number is: {}".format(revNum))
```